# Align the middle top of an SVG text element with a point?

Tags: svg, text

I'm trying to position a <text> element so that the middle top of the text is at a particular point.

Is there a way to do that with CSS? Do I have to get the bounding box of the text element and do the calculations myself?

Here is some javascript code which is basically what I want to do. It translates the top middle of the text's bounding box to the point (x0,y0):

```
function middle_top(text, x0, y0) {
    let svg = document.getElementById("the-svg")
    let t = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "text")
    t.setAttribute("x", 0)
    t.setAttribute("y", 0)
    t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
    svg.appendChild(t)
    let bbox = t.getBBox()
    let dx = x0 - (bbox.x + bbox.width/2)
    let dy = y0 - bbox.y
    t.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${dx}, ${dy})`)
}
```

And here is the HTML for `the-svg` element:

```
        <svg id="the-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
        </svg>
```

I tried `text-top` with various baseline directives, but maybe I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: Please add a code snippet containing your svg. It's also not clear what you mean by "middle top of the text" (x-height?). Have you tested properties like [`dominant-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) or [`dy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) for baseline offsets?

Comment: Question updated with more details.

Comment: pardon me, but we definitely have to see the `#the-svg` markup to give any advice (since the javaScript doesn't create a self contained svg element). `new_svg_element()` also implies you're using either custom or library/framework based methods. You could also copy the svg output via Firefox/Chrome DevTools and illustrate what's wrong and what should be the desired rendered result. Ideally simplify your code to a running snippet. If your svg is too big, you can share a codepen/jsFiddle/codesandbox ... etc. link. (BTW: svg  `<text>`  is rather "unintuitive" hence we need the code)

Comment: Ok - code updated. The `new_svg_element`  function was just a simple helper routine. Also added the HTML for `the-svg` element.

Answer (score 1):

I guess by "top" you mean the visual top - most likely the uppercase/capital letter height.

According to your `transform` values I assume you want your text to be center aligned around the defined x/y point coordinates: use `text-anchor:middle`.

You need to position/offset text elemnts according to their **current font-size.**

```js
const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const svg = document.getElementById("the-svg");
middle_top("SampleText", 10, 1, 50, 50);
middle_top("Hamburgefonstiv", 8, 0.5, 200, 150);

function middle_top(text, fontSize, yOffset, x0, y0) {
  let t = document.createElementNS(ns, "text");
  //illustrate exact x and y position
  addLine(svg, x0, y0);

  //position text elements
  t.setAttribute("x", x0);
  t.setAttribute("y", y0);
  t.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
  t.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
  t.textContent = text;
  svg.appendChild(t);

  //adjust text element height to uppercase letters height
  let ascenderRatio = 0.7;
  let bbox = t.getBBox();
  let dy = fontSize * ascenderRatio;
  t.setAttribute("dy", dy * yOffset);
}

function addLine(svg, x0, y0) {
  let line1 = document.createElementNS(ns, "line");
  line1.setAttribute("x1", 0);
  line1.setAttribute("x2", "100%");
  line1.setAttribute("y1", y0);
  line1.setAttribute("y2", y0);
  let line2 = document.createElementNS(ns, "line");
  line2.setAttribute("x1", x0);
  line2.setAttribute("x2", x0);
  line2.setAttribute("y1", 0);
  line2.setAttribute("y2", '100%');
  //add lines
  svg.appendChild(line1);
  svg.appendChild(line2);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

svg text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg line {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 2;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg id="the-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
</svg>
```

The bounding box of a text element doesn't tell anything about the **visual height of a text – e.g the capital letter height**.
Usually you can approximate a scaling factor since most font faces/families have a captital letter height of ~ 70–75% relative to their font size.

However, this is not by any means standardized and might deviate significantly depending on the particular font design.

So your `middle_top()` might better include additional arguments for current font-size and additional y-offsets.

See also: ["Typography – The Anatomy of Letters"](https://www.loveofgraphics.com/typography/typography-letters/)